# To prevent SQL-injection in user-defined formulae, is character whitelisting enough?

Tags: sql-injection

In my SaaS app, I want to give customers user-defined arithmetic expression formulae, with plus minus multiple and divide, and if else

For example, the customer might enter a formula like

```
CASE
WHEN sales * 2 > 100 THEN 'A'
WHEN sales > 100 THEN 'B'
ELSE 'C'
END
```

The final SQL would just be

```
SELECT <formula> FROM metrics WHERE client_id = <id of the customer>;
```

It is an oversimplified example but basically has everything I want to do

Not sure if prepared statements would work as the target DB might move to different analytical systems

I plan on doing a simple character whitelist, i.e. arithmetic operators, a-zA-Z0-9, comparison characters, spaces, and single quote

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\'+-*\/\s><=()]+$/
```

Would this be sufficient to prevent SQL-injection in this case?

Comment: this "white list" is pretty much everything that's needed for a succesful exploit, including a comment. I am afraid there is no cheap way and you have to validate these formulas first;

Answer (score 1):

No, using a regular expression like the one you show would not protect against unauthorized expressions.

The example of allowing a user to write an expression and executing a query including that expression *is* SQL injection, by definition.

The way to prevent SQL injection is never to copy the user's input into SQL syntax at all. But that means users cannot execute their custom expressions verbatim.

Here's how one might provide custom functions safely: allow a user to submit an expression for your review. You would vet it, and if you determine it is safe, you can store that expression as an option they can choose in the future. For example, your UI would present a list of approved expressions, and they would choose one by its id. Then on the server-side, your could would look up the expression they specified in their request, and use that in an SQL query. Thus the dynamic part of the query could only be content that you had previously reviewed, not their literal input.

Comment: When you say "submit an expression for your review", you don't mean manually, right? Formula field is a very common feature

Comment: Yes, I mean manually. Formula field is a very common feature, just like electrical fires are very common.

Comment: That is a massive statement man, pretty much every large SaaS enterprise app / BI tool would be described as "electrical fire"

Comment: Yep, that's right. They are practicing SQL injection by design.